# How can I reload my ViewModel in WPF without restarting application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using WPF MVVM trying to figure out what would be the best way to reload my ViewModel (entire View would work as well I suppose).

The data behind my Model is parsed out of a series of flat files stored within a directory. The location of the directory is saved in the .Settings file and can be the user via a popup window.

If the user changes updates the directory they want to use, how can I recreate my ViewModel so that the data being used is what is in the new directory?

I guess it would be akin to changing to a different database while the app is running if that is what I had as a datastore. Currently I show a message asking the user to restart the application.

Here is the important code:

```
public SignalViewModel()
{
    _trafficSignals = new ObservableCollection<TrafficSignal>(DataAccess.TrafficSignalRepository.GetTrafficSignals());
}



public static List<TrafficSignal> GetTrafficSignals()
{
    string dataStore = Properties.Settings.Default.SaveLocation;
    var signals = new List<TrafficSignal>();
    if (Directory.Exists(dataStore))
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(dataStore, "CP*.SAV");
        Array.Sort(files);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            signals.Add(LoadFile(file));
        }
    }
    return signals;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this problem with two events:

1. Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the settings.
2. In the `TrafficSignalRepository` I would then implement an event (e.g. `SaveLocationChanged`) which you raise after the PropertyChanged event of the settings was raised for the `SaveLocation`-Property

Then you can register for the `SaveLocationChanged` event inside of the ViewModel. In the registered event handler you just call `GetTrafficSignals()` again, assign the new value to the field and raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event of the ViewModel. The rest should be done for you automatically by data binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the saved settings using

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
```

And then call `GetTrafficSignals()` again?

Although having said that, I have had some issues in using the Reload method in the past...